# why is the block of code inside func call is not executed?

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp

I am trying to implement an Xmpp client into my application.I am planning on using the following code inside my application but some part of the code doesn't seem to be executed which prevents me to connect to a server. https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios

I am trying to connect to a server with my jabberID and password but for some this code is never executed:

```
if let _ = error {
     let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message: "An error occured: \(error)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
         alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
         //do smt
     }))
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
     } else {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
     }
```

Here is the whole code that is related to the problem:

```
    @IBAction func validate(sender: AnyObject) {
            if OneChat.sharedInstance.isConnected() {
                OneChat.sharedInstance.disconnect()
                usernameTextField.hidden = false
                passwordTextField.hidden = false
                validateButton.setTitle("Validate", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            } else {
                OneChat.sharedInstance.connect(username: self.usernameTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) {(stream, error) -> Void in
                    if let _ = error {
                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message: "An error occured: \(error)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                            //do smt
                        }))
                        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    } else {
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

public typealias OneChatConnectCompletionHandler = (stream: XMPPStream, error: DDXMLElement?) -> Void

public func connect(username username: String, password: String, completionHandler completion:OneChatConnectCompletionHandler) {
        if isConnected() {
            streamDidConnectCompletionBlock = completion
            self.streamDidConnectCompletionBlock!(stream: self.xmppStream!, error: nil)
            return
        }

        if (username == "kXMPPmyJID" && NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(kXMPP.myJID) == "kXMPPmyJID") || (username == "kXMPPmyJID" && NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(kXMPP.myJID) == nil) {
            streamDidConnectCompletionBlock = completion
            streamDidConnectCompletionBlock!(stream: self.xmppStream!, error: DDXMLElement(name: "Please set crendentials before trying to connect"))
            return
        }

        if username != "kXMPPmyJID" {
            setValue(username, forKey: kXMPP.myJID)
            setValue(password, forKey: kXMPP.myPassword)
        }

        if let jid = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(kXMPP.myJID) {
            xmppStream?.myJID = XMPPJID.jidWithString(jid)
        } else {
            streamDidConnectCompletionBlock = completion //was false
            streamDidConnectCompletionBlock!(stream: self.xmppStream!, error: DDXMLElement(name: "Bad username"))
        }

        if let password = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(kXMPP.myPassword) {
            self.password = password
        } else {
            streamDidConnectCompletionBlock = completion //was false
            streamDidConnectCompletionBlock!(stream: self.xmppStream!, error: DDXMLElement(name: "Bad password"))
        }
        try! xmppStream!.connectWithTimeout(XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)

        streamDidConnectCompletionBlock = completion
    }
```

Comment: exactly which part of your code is not getting executed.

Comment: As I have indicated above code starting with 
if let _ = error

Comment: What is the value of error your are getting? Or your response block is not called ?

Comment: I am not getting any error, but as far as I understand from the code,

Comment: if error value is nil then it should execute else part. Try to check explicitly for error!=nil

Comment: I am not getting any error, but as far as I understand from the code, after OneChat.sharedInstance.connect is called if an error happens it should present an alert and if not, it should dismiss the present view controller. But neither happens, it is skipping the code starting with ' if let _ = error '. I think it should at least execute 'self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you are expecting a time-out that never will happened (configuration of the library)
I had the same problem and, finally, I fount that my problem was hostname and port. Did you try to use something like this:

```
let usuario = "name@domain.com";

OneChat.sharedInstance.connect(username: usuario, password: pass) { (stream, error) -> Void in


        if let _ = error {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message: "An error occured: \(error)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                //do something
            }))
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("I did it!")

        }
    }
```